# How to update to Clementine 1.2.3

Tags: 14.04, updates, music, clementine

I have `Clementine 1.2` version installed in my Ubuntu 14.04 but I want to update it to Clementine 1.2.3 (which i think is the last version).

I read  [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-clementine-music-player-1-2-3-in-ubuntu-14-04/) that I need to add the Clementine PPA via the terminal, update it and then install it but I just need to know if this is the correct way to update it, it seems to me that this makes a clean installation of the program itself but I just want to update it to the latest version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Quoted from Official site](https://www.clementine-player.org/downloads)

Dependencies for Ubuntu Precise (12.04)(if you use newer versions skip this step)

New versions of Clementine require GStreamer 1.0 which wasn't included in Ubuntu 12.04. If you get errors installing Clementine you should add the GStreamer PPA as well:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gstreamer-developers/ppa
```

You can download the latest version of Clementine on Ubuntu from the official PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:me-davidsansome/clementine
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clementine
```

#### Back to your question

> update it and then install it but I just need to know if this is the
>   correct way to update it, it seems to me that this makes a clean
>   installation of the program itself but i just want to update it to the
>   latest version.

Please note that updating a package is done in the same manner as installing using `apt-get install` command and this what make you confused.

`man apt-get`

```
 install
           install is followed by one or more packages desired for
           installation or upgrading....
```

#### What does this mean?

When you run the command `apt-get install` it will first check whether this app is already installed in your system or not, if the app is not founded then it will install it else it's going to update it if there exist a newer version.

So now for y our case when adding the official PPA above then you are making newer versions available to be installed/updated since Ubuntu repositories always be some steps below official PPAs.

So when you add this PPA and run `apt-get install` it will fetch the app and check whether there is a newer version or not(since you already installed)m so it will find a newer version from the added repository so it's going to update your app to newer version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that will update Clementine to the latest version. the official [site](https://www.clementine-player.org/downloads) also has the PPA install.